# Why can't I change the value using my input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I´m trying to change one value of my parent. My parent container send the data to `PersonalComponent` and `PersonalComponent` send the data to my `AvatarComponent` what is the component where I have my input

I receive the props in my `PersonalComponent` that's I know, but when I send the data to `AvatarComponent`, I think I can change the data of my container that's the parent of `PersonalComponent`

This is the parent of all:

```
class HandlePersonal extends Component {
  state = {
    ...this.props.user
  };

  handleUsername = e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.props.dispatch({
      type: "CHANGE_USERNAME",
      payload: this.state.displayName
    });
  };

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ ...this.state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    alert(2);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <PersonalComponent
        handleUsername={this.handleUsername}
        handleChange={this.handleChange}
        data={this.state}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

This is my `PersonalComponent`

```
const PersonalComponent = props => {
  return (
    <div id="personal">
      <h2>My profile</h2>
      <Card>
        <div id="personal-container">
          <div id="cover">
            <CoverComponent />
          </div>
          <div id="avatar">
            <AvatarComponent
              data={props.data.photoURL}
              onChange={props.handleChange}
            />
          </div>
          <div id="user-name">
            <form onSubmit={props.handleUsername}>
              <InputText
                name="displayName"
                value={props.data.displayName}
                onChange={props.handleChange}
              />
              <Button id="save-username" label="Ok" />
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I know that it's working because I had `alert(props.data)` inside `PersonalComponent`

And then, this is my `AvatarComponent`

```
<h1>Value: {props.data}</h1>
<input name="photoURL" value={props.data} onChange={props.handleChange} />
```

And here, if I `alert(props.data)` I receive null that's the actual value of `photoURL` in the `HandlePersonal` but I can't change the value using my input. Why?

**I want to make that when i write in my input inside AvatarComponent the value of `HandleContainer` change**

Comment: Where, in my avatarComponent?

Comment: My avatar component is a Functional Component. 

    const AvatarComponent = props => {

Comment: PersonalComponent is functional too?

Comment: Yes, PersonalComponent is a function

Comment: Where is `this.handleChange` definition?

Comment: In my HandlePersonal container

handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ ...this.state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    alert(2);
  };

Comment: This works because I have another input in PersonalComponent and works fine

Comment: You have to add all relevant code to the question

Comment: That's not relevant because I only need to know if can I send data like this.

Comment: Container => PersonalComponent => AvatarComponent -------

AvatarComponent => PersonalComponent => Container

Comment: This question is very difficult to follow. You might want to re-write it

Comment: I had modified it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short:
`HandlePersonal.handleChange()` needs to call `this.setState('photoUrl': 'input value')` to update the state.

Lemme knwo if you need detailed answer..im on my phone so not so convenient.

*EDIT*
`<input name="photoURL" value={props.data} onChange={props.onChange} />`
Because u pass it as onChange

Comment: Bro, that´s not the problem because I have another input that change displayName of the state and it work. See <InputText
                name="displayName"
                value={props.data.displayName}
                onChange={props.handleChange}
              />

Comment: I had it same xd <input name="photoURL" value={props.data} onChange={props.handleChange} />

Comment: Ohh true, it´s onChange and not HandleChange! I´ll try!